# Does spark have key-value pair processing by default?

Tags: apache-spark

Mapreduce works in terms of key-value pair by default

It has mainly two phases.

1. Map
2. Reduce

My question is

1. Does Spark works in terms of key-value pair by default?
2. Does spark has Map phase and reduce phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark integrates with hadoop APIs, so:

1. Spark supports, among others, key-value pair operations straight out of the box, once you have mapped your data to key-value pairs.
2. Spark supports performing map and reduce operations straight out of the box.